# Layout constraint error

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm struggling with auto layout in XCode6 so I'm trying to set the constraints in code.
I have a scrollview wich covers most of the screen. Inside the scrollview I've placed a button, a imgview and a textview. The button is a fixed 44px and now I want to split what's left of the scrollview between the imgview and textview (resulting in them being the same size).

this is my SubViewsDidLoad function:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height;
    let scrollViewTop = self.navigationBar.frame.height + self.navigationBar.frame.minY
    let scrollViewBottom = self.toolBar.frame.height


 // set scrollView frame

    println ("navigationbarTop: ", scrollViewTop)
    println ("toolbarHeight: ", scrollViewBottom)
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollViewTop, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight-(scrollViewTop+scrollViewBottom))

// set btnLocation size & constraints

    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.btnLocatie, attribute:.CenterX, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:self.view,attribute:.CenterX, multiplier:1, constant:0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.btnLocatie, attribute:.Top, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:self.scrollView,attribute:.Top, multiplier:1, constant:8))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.btnLocatie, attribute:.Left, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:self.scrollView,attribute:.Left, multiplier:1, constant:8))

 // set imageview size & constraints

    //X - align to center
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.imgAfbeelding, attribute:.CenterX, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:self.view, attribute:.CenterX, multiplier:1, constant:0))
    //Top - Scrollview+8
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.imgAfbeelding, attribute:.Top, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:self.btnLocatie, attribute:.Bottom, multiplier:1, constant:+8))
    //Left - scrollview leftside+8
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint( item:self.imgAfbeelding, attribute:.Left, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:self.scrollView, attribute:.Left, multiplier:1, constant:8))
    //Size - scrollView size
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.imgAfbeelding, attribute:.Bottom, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:self.scrollView, attribute:.Bottom, multiplier:1, constant:(scrollView.frame.height-btnLocatie.frame.height+16)/2))

 // set textview size & constraints

    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint( item:self.txtTekst, attribute:.Left, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:self.scrollView, attribute:.Left, multiplier:1, constant:0))

    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.txtTekst, attribute:.Top, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:self.imgAfbeelding, attribute:.Bottom, multiplier:1, constant:+8))

    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.txtTekst, attribute:.Bottom, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:self.scrollView, attribute:.Bottom, multiplier:1, constant:scrollView.frame.height-8))
 }
```

When I run the code, at first everything looks good. But when I rotate the device the console shows a lot of constraint errors and the position and size of the image view and textview are completely off.

I'm guessing there's a better way to get this to work properly, but I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.btnLocatie.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
self.imgAfbeelding.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

Comment: you got the answer or not

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do anything for me.
Example of the errors I'm getting:
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x1467c9b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(143)-[UIButton:0x14563d70'Add Location'](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x1456bbb0 )>
...
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.